# SSH.NET - No suitable authentication method found

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ftp, sftp

This is my code using SSH.NET

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
{                
    sftp.Connect();  
}
```

It works on a SFTP I installed on my local computer but when I point it at a real SFTP server from a client I get a Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication.

I cannot find any documentation on what authentication methods I should be using and on File Zilla a simple user name and password is doing the trick.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer to my problem is that it wasn't an sftp server. It was a simple ftp server so i just used a webrequest.

Check the server is actually an sftp server first.

Comment: That's exactly what I expected and what we could have easily determined from the FileZilla log.

Answer (score 40):

I found the answer (at least for my problem, which seems to be the same as the op requested):

I had to change the Authentication to `KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod`

So this works now:

```
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod keybAuth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(SFTP_USR);
keybAuth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);

ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo(SFTP_HST, SFTP_PRT, SFTP_USR, keybAuth);

using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(conInfo))
{
    sftp.Connect();

    // Do SFTP Stuff, Upload, Download,...

    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```

`HandleKeyEvent` then passes the Password:

```
private void HandleKeyEvent(object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
    {
        if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            prompt.Response = SFTP_PWD;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation [here](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/541#issuecomment-507103900): *"This one was doing my head in. It turned out some servers do not support PasswordAuthenticationMethod, so you'll have to use keyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod, and then handle the AuthenticationPrompt event to provide the password:"*