# Use SSH.NET to connect using SSH Key and Two-factor Authentication

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh-keys, two-factor-authentication, ssh.net

I'm trying to use SSH.NET library (v2020.0.2 - latest) on C# Desktop application, to connect to a remote Linux (Debian) server.

The SSH server is configured as follows:

- Use SSH Keys (RSA) with passphrase
- Use `libpam-google-authenticator` to enable 2FA using Google Authenticator app
- On `sshd_config` file:

  - `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive`
  - `PasswordAuthentication no`
  - `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`
  - `UsePAM yes`

This is the code I'm using to establish the connection:

```cs
try
{
    PrivateKeyFile privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".ssh", "id_rsa"), "passphrase");
    SshClient sshClient = new SshClient("192.168.0.1", 22, "user", privateKey);
    sshClient.Connect(); // --> Exception
    SshCommand command = sshClient.CreateCommand("ls -la");
    command.Execute();
    string answer = command.Result;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

But it's giving me the following Exception:

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshAuthenticationException: 'No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (keyboard-interactive).'

According to SSH.NET [README.md](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET#features) on GitHub it should be compatible with 2FA but I'm not sure where is the real issue.

[image: SSH.Net Features list]

Also, how am I supposed to handle the Verification Code prompt?

***Note**: If I connect from the Windows 10 Command Prompt using `ssh` command from the same PC, it works. It first asks for the SSH Key passphrase and then it asks for the Verification Code.*

##### 2022-09-02 Update

**Updated code using SSH.NET**

```cs
try
{
    PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod privateKeyAuthentication = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("user", 
        new PrivateKeyFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".ssh", "id_ecdsa"), "passphrase"));
    
    KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod keyboardAuthentication = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod("user");
    keyboardAuthentication.AuthenticationPrompt += KeyboardAuthentication_AuthenticationPrompt;
    
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.0.1", 22, "user", privateKeyAuthentication, keyboardAuthentication);
    SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
    sshClient.Connect();
    SshCommand command = sshClient.CreateCommand("ls -la");
    command.Execute();
    string answer = command.Result;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}

private async void KeyboardAuthentication_AuthenticationPrompt(object sender, Renci.SshNet.Common.AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
    {
        if (prompt.Request.StartsWith("Password"))
            prompt.Response = "password"; // Hard coded here just for the sample
        else if (prompt.Request.StartsWith("Verification"))
            prompt.Response = "..."; // Insert Verification code at runtime using here a Debugger breakpoint
    }
}
```

**Client connection ssh verbose log**

```
C:\Users\my.user>ssh -vvv admin@192.168.133.128 -i C:\Users\my.user\.ssh\id_ecdsa.pem
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.133.128 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.133.128 [192.168.133.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pem.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\my.user\\.ssh\\id_ecdsa.pem type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pem-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pem-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\my.user\\.ssh\\id_ecdsa.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.133.128:22 as 'admin'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\my.user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\my.user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.133.128
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:--<OMITTED>--
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\my.user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\my.user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.133.128
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/my.user/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '192.168.133.128' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\my.user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\my.user\\.ssh\\id_ecdsa.pem  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\my.user\\.ssh\\id_ecdsa.pem
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\my.user\.ssh\id_ecdsa.pem':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ECDSA SHA256:--<OMITTED>--
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Verification code:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.133.128 ([192.168.133.128]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:850 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys:3: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
The programs included are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Last login: Thu Sep  1 15:37:31 2022 from 192.168.133.1
┌─[admin@server]─[~]
└──╼ $
```

##### 2022-09-13 Update

Here I'm posting the log files from `sshd` in verbose debug mode (`-ddd` option) when connecting from `cmd.exe` (**OK**) and from my application using SSH.NET (**NOT WORKING**), both with same user credentials.

***NOTE**: I used PasteBin since the logs where too long for pasting here inside the question.*

- [Connection from cmd.exe](https://pastebin.com/TXe2AtwA)
- [Connection from SSH.NET](https://pastebin.com/zD2ZhVVK)

Some differences I noticed:

SSH.NET

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Renci.SshNet.SshClient.0.0.1
---- What does it means 'no match'? ----
debug1: no match: Renci.SshNet.SshClient.0.0.1

...

debug3: PAM: sshpam_query entering
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
---- There is no do_pam_account here ----
debug3: PAM: Authentication failure
PAM: Authentication failure for admin from 192.168.133.1
```

cmd.exe

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH compat 0x04000000

...

debug3: PAM: sshpam_query entering
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: do_pam_account: called
debug2: do_pam_account: auth information in SSH_AUTH_INFO_0
```

Answer (score 3):

From `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, I assume the `libpam-google-authenticator` is implemented by keyboard-interactive authentication. For that, see [SSH.NET - No suitable authentication method found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34875331/850848).

To combine it with private key factor, do something like this:

```
var privateKeyAuth = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, privateKey);

var keybAuth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
keybAuth.AuthenticationPrompt +=
    delegate (object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your implementation of the prompt. Something like this:
        if ((e.Prompts.Count() != 1) ||
            (e.Prompts.First().Request != "Verification code:"))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected auth prompt");
        }
        e.Prompts.First().Response = "verification code";
    };

var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, username, privateKeyAuth, keybAuth);

var sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
```